# two questions about primes

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, open-problem

I'm very ignorant about results in number theory concerning the primes. Please let me know if these are open conjectures or easy problems:

1. There are infinitely many primes of the form $n!+1$
2. There is a polynomial with integer coefficients which is prime for infinitely many integer inputs.

Edit: Yeah sorry I meant when the degree is at least 2. I know of Dirichlet for degree 1.

Comment: 1. - Open problem (factorial primes), 2.- Open problem (Buniakovski's Conjecture)

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'll delete.

Comment: Regarding 2. What do you mean by "is prime"? That f(x) is a prime for infinitely many integer values of x?

Comment: and here's the link:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture

Comment: The second problem is a theorem when the polynomial is linear with relatively prime coefficients (Dirichlet's theorem).

Comment: number $2$ is in fact true, there is a polynomial, I believe in $f\in\mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_{26}]$ of degree $25$, such that the set of prime numbers coincides with the set of positive values taken by $f$. It is called Matijasevic polynomial.

Comment: Wouldn't f(x)=x work? f(x) is prime for infinitely many integers x. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Dasherman I'm assuming it's about nontrivial polynomials (Degree >1)

Comment: @Dasherman: The second conjecture should read there is a polynomial in one variable of degree $\gt 1$ with integer coefficients which represents infinitely many primes.

Comment: @Ferra- I think you misunderstood the question asked, that, in 2 op is interested in knowing whether there exists a polynomial giving infinite prime outputs on infinite integer inputs and NOT  always giving primes

Comment: Side note: Your statement #1 reminds me of the proof that for every $n$ there exists a sequence of at least $n$ consecutive **non-prime** numbers. That's irrelevant to the question of course, but I thought you might like to know it...

Comment: barak manos that is a classic, I know it already. I meant deg>1 for #2; I've made an edit in the post to reflect that. I know n^2 +1 is open but I thought at least one deg 2 polynomial would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. These (and those of the form $n!-1$) are called [factorial primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime). We don't know if there are infinitely many.
2. As pointed out by others, the polynomial $x$ works. More generally, $ax + b$ works when $a$ and $b$ are coprime; this follows from [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). 
   For polynomials of degree at least two, not much is known. 
   Even $x^2 + 1$ is a mystery. 
   Iwaniec proved that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $n^2 + 1$ has at most $2$ prime factors.
   If a polynomial map $f$ takes on infinitely many prime values, 
   then $f$'s leading coefficient is positive, $f$ is irreducible over the integers, and the numbers $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $\dotsc$ do not have a common factor bigger than one. [Bunyakovsky's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) asserts that these necessary conditions are in fact sufficient. (To check the last condition, it is enough to find just one pair $n$, $m$ of integers with $f(n)$, $f(m)$ coprime.) We don't know any degree-at-least-two polynomial for which the Bunyakovsky conjecture holds.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that every "prime" polynomial (one which cannot be "broken" into a product of two polynomials) with integer coefficients generates infinitely many primes. If this has not be proved, then at least it would be "worth" to be stated as a conjecture, because as OP's statement #2 is currently phrased, there are several trivial examples that prove it: $f(x)=x,f(x)=2x+1,f(x)=4x+1,f(x)=4x+3,f(x)=6x+1,f(x)=6x+5$, etc.

Comment: KCd already stated that linear polynomials $ax + b$ (which happen to be "prime" (i.e. irreducible)) take on prime values infinitely often when $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Your conjecture is false; the irreducible polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + x + 2$ generates only the prime $2$; every output is even, as $f(x) = x(x+1)+2 \equiv 0\pmod 2$ for all integers $x$.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, but doesn't that mean that OP's statement #2 is a proved fact (and not a conjecture, as you mention in your answer)?

Comment: As stated, Joshua's 2 is true. I jumped to the assumption of the nontrivial case: that he was asking for a polynomial of degree $> 1$.